# GraphQL nested query arguments?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

When building a GraphQL API, is it possible to allow arguments on nested query properties? i.e. I've implemented an `orderBy` arg for a top-level `tasks` query like so:

```
query {
  tasks(orderBy: { order: asc }) {
    title
  }
}
```

and this works fine, but I would like to be able to query a `collection` of `task`s and add the query arguments to the nested `tasks` property like this:

```
query {
  collection {
    id
    name
    tasks(orderBy: { order: asc }) {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't recognize the arguments by default, so I assume if it is possible, then there is some further set up required. I get this error when I try that query: `"Unknown argument \"orderBy\" on field \"tasks\" of type \"Collection\"."`

P.S. I'm using `graphql-yoga` with `prisma` on the backend.

Comment: It is possible. Could you share your setup if possible like are you using Nexus with Prisma?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **nexus/schema** and **nexus-plugin-prisma** ? If you do, you have to activate ordering in your collection task model like this `t.model.tasks({ ordering: true })`

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I worked it out in the end. I just needed to pass the `args` to the `tasks` invocation in the `Collection.tasks` resolver:

```js
Collection: {
  tasks: (parent, args, context) => {
    const { id } = parent

    const collection = context.prisma.collection.findOne({
      where: { id },
    })

    return collection.tasks(args) // ← pass in `args` here
  },
},
```

I also needed to add the `orderBy` option in my schema for the `Collection.tasks` field (I previously only had it on `Query.tasks`)